# Retrieve an image from RESTlet API

Tags: java, restlet-2.0

I am creating a REST API in JAVA using RESTlet 2.0.  I want to create an API call that will return an image from the database in a similar way as Facebook is doing in its Graph API.

Basically, I will do a **GET** to e.g.

```
    http://localhost:8080/myAPI/{session_id}/img/p?id=1
```

This will then retrieve the blob data from the DB and then return the image in such a way that the user can display it like this:

```
    <img src="http://localhost:8080/myAPI/{session_id}/img/p?id=1">
```

I know that I will probably need to set the content-type in the header to Image/PNG (assuming the image is a PNG of course), but what I'm struggling with is returning the data correctly for this to work.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

not sure about 2.0, however in 2.2 you could use something like this:

```
@Get
public Representation getImage() {

    ...
    byte[] data = ...

    ObjectRepresentation<byte[]> or=new ObjectRepresentation<byte[]>(data, MediaType.IMAGE_PNG) {
        @Override
        public void write(OutputStream os) throws IOException {
            super.write(os);
            os.write(this.getObject());
        }
    };

    return or; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks @trigras, gonna try this.

Comment: @tigras: YOU ARE A LEGEND!  Works like a charm!  How do you +1000000 someone's rep on here!

Answer (score 2):

Using 2.2 there is a ByteArrayRepresentation type.

```
@Get("image/jpeg")
public void getIcon() {
    byte[ ] your_images_bytes = ...
    ByteArrayRepresentation bar 
        = new ByteArrayRepresentation(your_images_bytes, MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG) ;
    getResponse().setEntity(bar);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my App I am returning a `byte array` from my REST method.
and the `content-type` is `image/png` as you have mentioned.